# Refresh query results from included php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update an included PHP file and get the refreshed results and variables from that file. The file `getmssg.php` is included in the foreach loop because I need in that file a row value. The variable `$ergebnis1` I get from the file `getmssg.php`.

How can I call/refresh the query values of the included PHP file without reloading the page?

```
<?php
include("chatmain.php");
?>
    <?php foreach ($result2 as $key => $row): ?>
        <?php include("getmssg.php"); ?>
        <li data-icon="false" name="listi5" class="listitem5">
            <a type="button" class="ui-btn" id=5"> 
                <?php if ($ergebnis1 > 0) {
                    echo '<span class="ui-li-count">'.$ergebnis1.'</span>';
                } ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What I have now:

```
function getmsg() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'getmssg.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            //alert(output);
        }
    });
}

var timer;      
function docount() {    
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        getmsg();
    }, 3000);
}

docount();
```

Comment: Try to load the file that have foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the php forEach inside a php function and call that function in the success callback of the ajax .It will update the contents without pageload

Comment: Thats only a piece of the list item into the loop. I have too any jquery functions that need values from that loop. If I make an extra file for that how should the browser know where the loop ends?

Comment: U want to asynchronously put contents into the file(getmsg.php) and get the contents without page load right???
..Dont add a new file.....inside the success call back execute the loop which will also loop through for every 3 seconds

Comment: Uhm could you make an example with my ajax request? :D I dont know what you mean with execute the loop into the success callback. Which loop?

Comment: where does that php foreach code lies?in a new file ?

Comment: Oh yes excuse me I forgot to post that too. Should I call know in my success function a new ajax request to the file with the loop named chatmain.php or what do you mean?

Comment: If u wanted without page load then that is the solution u can go far.But that is not a recommended way of doing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105005/discussion-between-vijaykrish93-and-bodoppels).